# HPA cannot get custom metric from Kafka exporter

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, azure-aks, hpa

I'm trying to use Prometheus, Custom metric, and Kafka Export for my helloworld HPA. Unfortunately, I get these error on HPA event said `unable to get metric kafka_consumergroup_lag: no metrics returned from custom metrics API`. Even I got value from kubectl cli. I google so many websites but no clue. Does anyone help me what I did wrong?

```
# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.24.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.23.5
```

```
# kubectl get apiservices
NAME                                   SERVICE                             AVAILABLE   AGE
v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io         monitoring/prometheus-adapter   True        28m
```

**Error from helloworld HPA**

```
# kubectl describe hpa/helloworld
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age   From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetPodsMetric           0s    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric kafka_consumergroup_lag: no metrics returned from custom metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  0s    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), first error is: failed to get pods metric value: unable to get metric kafka_consumergroup_lag: no metrics returned from custom metrics API
```

**helloworld HPA**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: helloworld
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: app-deployment
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: helloworld
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: kafka_consumergroup_lag
      target:
        type: Value
        averageValue: "1000"
```

**How do I install prometheus-adapter**

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus-adapter prometheus-community/prometheus-adapter -n monitoring \
--set serviceAccounts.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.name=microservice \
--set prometheus.url="http://prometheus-server"
```

**How do I install prometheus-kafka-exporter**

```
helm upgrade --install -f prometheus_kafka_exporter.yaml prometheus-kafka-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-kafka-exporter -n monitoring \
--set serviceAccounts.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.name=microservice \
--set verbosity=0 \
--set sarama.logEnabled=true \
--set log.level=debug \
--set liveness.enabled=true \
--set readiness.enabled=true \

cat prometheus_kafka_exporter.yaml
annotations:
  prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
  prometheus.io/port: '9308'
  prometheus.io/path: /metrics
```

**How do I install prometheus**

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus -n monitoring \
--set serviceAccounts.alertmanager.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.nodeExporter.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.pushgateway.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.server.create=false \
--set serviceAccounts.alertmanager.name=microservice \
--set serviceAccounts.nodeExporter.name=microservice \
--set serviceAccounts.pushgateway.name=microservice \
--set serviceAccounts.server.name=microservice
```

**My helloworld Custom Metric Data Output**

```
# kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/metrics/kafka_consumergroup_lag  | jq .
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/%2A/metrics/kafka_consumergroup_lag"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Namespace",
        "name": "monitoring",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      },
      "metricName": "kafka_consumergroup_lag",
      "timestamp": "2022-07-06T09:49:20Z",
      "value": "70384686",
      "selector": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**My helloworld Custom Metric Data Output**

```
# kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/b2p-monitoring/pod/*/kafka_consumergroup_lag | jq .
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/b2p-monitoring/pod/%2A/kafka_consumergroup_lag"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Pod",
        "namespace": "monitoring",
        "name": "prometheus-kafka-exporter-57c94bd7cf-9xsrn",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      },
      "metricName": "kafka_consumergroup_lag",
      "timestamp": "2022-07-06T09:49:46Z",
      "value": "70384686",
      "selector": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Change the Prometheus thingy to the same as namespace that the service presents. Then change the HPA metric from `type: Pods` to `type: Object`.

Phew~ HPA is working now.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: helloworld
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: app-deployment
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: helloworld
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metric:
        name: kafka_consumergroup_lag
      describedObject:
        apiVersion: /v1
        kind: Namespace
        name: helloworld
      target:
        type: Value
        value: "1000"
```

Comment: What is " the prometheus thingy" ?